# Threads are being blocked while receiving data from RSS feed Adapter

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

We have a common ThreadPoolTaskExecutor and it is set in PollerMetadata so RSS feed adapter will
receive data from given rss feed parallely.

Now there are 9 Threads created from ThreadPoolTaskExecutor with prefix My-APP-Thread
and each thread will run peridocally.

After certain time, 8 of theses 9 Threads are in blocked state and waiting for 9th Thread to release the lock.

we are using spring-integration-core 5.5.0 and spring-integration-feed 5.5.0

Here is snapshot of thread dump

```
My-APP-Thread-9
Stack Trace is:
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:475)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:469)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:69)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1239)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$300(SSLSocketImpl.java:75)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:926)
- locked <0x000000063d80e658> (a sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
- locked <0x000000063d80e678> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:848)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1593)
- locked <0x000000063d80e730> (a sun.net.www.protocol.https.delegatehttpsurlconnection)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
- locked <0x000000063d80e730> (a sun.net.www.protocol.https.delegatehttpsurlconnection)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
- locked <0x000000063d80e850> (a sun.net.www.protocol.https.httpsurlconnectionimpl)
at com.rometools.rome.io.XmlReader.<init>(XmlReader.java:285)
at com.rometools.rome.io.XmlReader.<init>(XmlReader.java:236)
at com.rometools.rome.io.XmlReader.<init>(XmlReader.java:214)
at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.getFeed(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:223)
- locked <0x00000003dd98b0e0> (a java.lang.Object)
at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.populateEntryList(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:201)
at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.doReceive(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:176)
- locked <0x00000003dd98b0c0> (a java.lang.Object)
at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.doReceive(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:57)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:142)
```

I dont know if this is some how connected to this
[dynamically-registered-beans-are-unresponsive-after-some-days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69663753/dynamically-registered-beans-are-unresponsive-after-some-days)

Comment: It appears to be blocked on a socket read - no response from server? Post the complete stack trace someplace like a GitHub gist or pastebin.

Comment: That SO thread might be related only if you use Spring Boot. But again: a single thread in a task scheduler is somehow not related here since you see those threads active from your `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`. Therefore no blocking on a single (if any) task scheduler thread.

Comment: @GaryRussell here is the full thread dump that you asked for https://github.com/pinkeshsagar-harptec/code-sample/blob/main/sample_thread_dump.txt . Everything was working fine for a week then all of sudden threads are blocked. It looks like connection is not getting timeout even when server is not giving response or holding connection for very long time.

Comment: Thread 9 is blocked reading from the socket; the other threads are blocked because the adapter can only serve one feed entry at a time. The problem appears to be a non-responsive server. Socket reads are not interruptible; it is not clear how to set a socket timeout on a UrlConnection; but that's what's needed.

Comment: @GaryRussell Thank you for looking into it. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: There is an overloaded constructor for `XmlReader` (in rometools) that takes a `UrlConnection`; you can set a `readTimeout` on a `UrlConnection`, but the Spring Integration `FeedEntryMessageSource` doesn't currently support that as an option. I suggest you open a new feature request GitHub issue. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues

Comment: See my answer for a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

We probably have to expose a `URLConnection` as an option for this `FeedEntryMessageSource`, but that's already a task for the mentioned https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3677.

As a workaround I'd suggest to look into a `org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource` and its

```
/**
 * Customize the given {@link HttpURLConnection}, obtained in the course of an
 * {@link #exists()}, {@link #contentLength()} or {@link #lastModified()} call.
 * <p>Sets request method "HEAD" by default. Can be overridden in subclasses.
 * @param con the HttpURLConnection to customize
 * @throws IOException if thrown from HttpURLConnection methods
 */
protected void customizeConnection(HttpURLConnection con) throws IOException {
```

to override.

So, you can call  desired `setConnectTimeout(int timeout)` and inject such a custom `Resource` into this `FeedEntryMessageSource`.

Comment: Thanks Artem; I didn't realize the `UrlResource` had support for customizing the connection - just for clarity, it's the `readTimeout` that needs to be set here (but setting the connection timeout is a good idea too).